# Solving matrix equation

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, difference-equations

How can I solve the forward equation

```
S[t]=C+A*S[t+1]*(Inverse((I-B*S(t+1)))*A
```

for t=1 to `t=10` and `S[11]=0`
with `S`, `A`, `C`, and `B` beeing 2*2 matrices?

```
A={{0.1,0},{0,0.1}}
B={{2,3},{-3,1}}, C={{0.2,0.6},{0.2,0}}, I={{1,0},{0,1}}
```

Comment: A={{0.1,0},{0,0.1}}

Comment: B={{2,3},{-3,1}}, C={{0.2,0.6},{0.2,0}}, I={{1,0},{0,1}}

Comment: Please include these in the question instead of posting them as comments, such that someone can just copy all the necessary code from the question.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
a = {{0.1, 0}, {0, 0.1}};
b = {{2, 3}, {-3, 1}};
c = {{0.2, 0.6}, {0.2, 0}};
i = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
```

and

```
s[t_] := {{s11[t], s12[t]}, {s21[t], s22[t]}}
```

one can see that `s12` and `s21` don't depend on `t` by evaluating

```
c + a*s[t + 1]*Inverse[i - b*s[t + 1]]*a
```

Therefore I set

```
s[11] = {{0, 0.6}, {0.2, 0}}
```

Redefining `s` with

```
s[t_] := s[t] = c + a*s[t + 1]*Inverse[i - b*s[t + 1]]*a
```

one can find `s` for `t = 10` and any other integer `t <= 11` using

```
s[10]
```

> ```
> {{0.2, 0.6}, {0.2, 0.}}
> ```

Comment: how can i define a loop for t=1 , t=10 , for above problem?

Comment: @mehrnoosh You can use `Table[s[t], {t, 10}]`.

Comment: Karsten 7. - I suspect the OP means for the recursion to be: `s[t_] := s[t] = c + a.s[t + 1].Inverse[i - b.s[t + 1]].a;` and the initial condition to be `s[11]={{0,0},{0,0}}`. Fixing these, you can get the iteration by `s[#] & /@ Range[10, 0, -1]`

Comment: @mehrnoosh Could you clarify if you mean [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html?q=Times)(`*`, element-wise multiplication) or [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html?q=Dot)(`.`, matrix product).

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}};
b = {{b1, b2}, {b3, b4}};
c = {{c1, c2}, {c3, c4}};
s[11] = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
s[10] = c + a.s[11].Inverse[IdentityMatrix[2] - b.s[11]].a
```

which immediately returns

```
{{c1, c2}, {c3, c4}}
```

Trying to use upper case characters, like C, for variable names results in errors. Trying to use "abstract" vectors and matricies results in errors. Trying to use * instead of . for matrix multiplication results in errors. In slightly more complicated questions you may need to use Simplify and possibly supply assumptions about variable domains.