# How can I solve the forward - backward matrix equation?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, numerical-integration, differential-equations

```
p[t]=S[t]*X[t]-g[t]
X[t+1]=(Inverse((I-B*S(t+1)))(A*X[t]-B*g[t+1]+D)
S[t]=C+A*S[t+1]*(Inverse((I-B*S(t+1)))*A
g[t]=A*S[t+1]*(Inverse((I-B*S(t+1)))(B*g[t+1]-D)+A*G[T+1]+E
```

For `t=1` to `t=10`

I want to  the different values of `S[t]` and `g[t]` at all points in time by backward loop; then get the corresponding values of `x[t]` and `p[t]` by forward loop.

That `S`, `A`, `C`, and `B` are $2\times2$ matrices and `P`, `X`, `D`, `E` and `g` are $2\times1$ matrices.

The boundary condition are:

```
S[11]={{0,0},{0,0}}, g[11]={{0},{0}}, X[1]={{1},{0}}, p[11]={{0},{0}}
A={{0.1,0},{0,0.1}} B={{2,3},{-3,1}}, C={{0.2,0.6},{0.2,0}}, I={{1,0},{0,1}} 
D={{2},{3}}, E={{1},{0}}
```

How can i do the Sensitivity Analysis for above parameters?

Comment: Preferably don't use variables starting with an uppercase letter. All of Mathematica's functions start with one and it is easy to inadvertently use one. In this case you have used the reserved words `I` (Sqrt[-1]) and `C` (used for constants in differential equation solutions)

Comment: See this one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76184/1783 for a really good hint

Answer (score 1):

```
A = {{0.1, 0}, {0, 0.1}};
B = {{2, 3}, {-3, 1}};
c = {{0.2, 0.6}, {0.2, 0}};
d = {2, 3};
e = {1, 0};
i = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
g[11] = {0, 0};
g[t_] := A.S[t+1].Inverse[i-B.S[t+1]].(B.g[t+1]-d)+A.g[t+1]+e;
p[11] = {0, 0};
p[t_] := S[t].X[t] - g[t];
S[11] = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
S[t_] := c + A.S[t + 1].Inverse[i - B*S[t + 1]].A ;
X[1] = {1, 0};
X[t_] := Inverse[i - B.S[t]].(A.X[t - 1] - B.g[t] + d);
For[j = 10, j >= 1, j--,
  g[j] = g[j];
  S[j] = S[j]
];
For[j = 1, j <= 10, j++,
  X[j] = X[j];
  p[j] = p[j]
]
```

After running that code you can inspect single values by evaluating things like

```
g[7]
```

or you can look at all values of g by evaluating

```
?g
```

Likewise for your other three functions.

Comment: how can i do the Sensitivity Analysis for above parameters?